# No more reputation for suggested edits?

Tags: bug, reputation, review, edits, suggested-edits

I have been editing posts since yesterday, and I haven't yet got any reputation points (+2).

And I even checked in my reputation points action tab, and all my edits are showing as approved as shown below:

[image]

When it says approved edit, then why am I not getting the +2 reputation points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> **Can I earn reputation?**
>
> - When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000. Like any other
>     reputation, the +2 is reversed if the edited post is ever deleted.
> - When a suggested edit is rejected, no penalty is given.
> - Once you have earned the edit privilege, your edits are no longer peer reviewed and no reputation is given for edits.

Since you have not yet earned the edit privilege, it looks like you have come up against "total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000".